# Permission Setuid

Tags: shell, operating-system

I want to know what is the purpose of s in chmod.

```
 tiago2@ubuntu:~$ ls -l file
 -rw-r--r-- 1 tiago2 tiago2 0 2013-01-20 17:05 file
 tiago2@ubuntu:~$ chmod g+s file
 tiago2@ubuntu:~$ ls -l file
 -rw-r-Sr-- 1 tiago2 tiago2 0 2013-01-20 17:05 file
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/what-is-sticky-bit-mode-suid-sgid-258719/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s` stand for set.

> The file permissions bits include an execute permission bit for file
>   owner, group and   other. When the execute bit for the owner is set to
>   "s" the set user ID bit is set. This causes any persons or processes
>   that run the file to have access to system resources as though they
>   are the owner of the file. When the execute bit for the group is set
>   to "s", the set group ID bit is set and the user running the program
>   is given access based on access permission for the group the file
>   belongs to.

The command:

```
chmod g+s file
```

sets the group ID bit on the file "file".

Comment: g for group, u for user [**Set User Identification Attribute**](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/usersguide/linux_ugfilesp.html)